# discordjs v14 - How to modify embed?

Tags: discord.js

i try make embed

```
const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setAuthor({ name: `name : ${name}` })
      .setColor(0x0099ff)
      .setTitle(`title: ${title}`)
      .setDescription(`content : ${content}`)
```

make embed!!

[image]

looking for discordjs14 guide

```
// Resending a received embed
const receivedEmbed = message.embeds[0];
const exampleEmbed = EmbedBuilder.from(receivedEmbed).setTitle('New title');

channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
----------------------------------------------
// Editing the embedded message content
const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setDescription('Description after the edit');

message.edit({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
```

i try to get message.embed[0]

```
async execute(interaction) {
   ...
   console.log(interaction.embed[0])
   ...
}
```

error:

[image]

i hope search title and edit embed...

Comment: Did you mean `interaction.embeds[0]`? You should include the code that throws that error.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros i was try ' try catch'  
ErrorMessage :  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an embed and edit it on an event, You should make thay message a var.

```js
const channel = <client>.channels.cache.get('channel_id');

let message = await channel.send({embeds: [exampleEmbed] });

// editing it

await message.edit({ embeds: [exampleEmbed1] });
```

Notes: Replace `<client>` with what you declared your client. it could be `client` , `bot` or anything you have declared it.

Answer (score 0):

fist you need to make embed message

```
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor("Your Color")
.setTitle("YourTitle")
.setThumbnail("your google image address")
.setImage("Your Google Image address")
.setDescription("Your Description")
```

and so much more stuff just type .set or .add it will show you so many of them

and for send the embed

```
message.reply({embeds : [embed]});
```